# Problems Connecting Asus Transformer TF101 to Mac OS X 10.92

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, google-maps

I am not able to connect my Asus tablet to my Mac. It has been recommended that I go and download the USB drivers for the tablet [here](http://www.asus.com/support/Download/28/1/Eee_Pad_Transformer_TF101/8/). Seemed easy enough. WRONG! USB drivers are well supported for Windows, but not Mac or Linux (odd). There is a third party application that Asus says you need to install called Splashtop Streamer for Windows or Mac in order to move forward with the installation of the drivers.

I gave that the old college try and much to my chagrin, Splashtop Streamer does not seem to have clear instruction on how to configure their product. I left a comment on one of their [pages](https://support-splashtoppersonal.splashtop.com/entries/21742727-Error-message-Your-6783-port-is-not-reachable?page=1#post_25461766) that discussed a error "Your 6783 port is not reachable", which seemed to be adversely effecting my completion of the installation process.

In summary, I can not install USB drivers in order to load my app onto my device to test. I am trying to test a Google Map App using V2 of the API. Apparently, the Eclipse and the Android Studio emulators to not render the new [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/setup#demo). So, I need to ship the app to a device.

Must I really buy a new one?

Comment: You should post this [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/). Your question isn't related to programming (which is what StackOverflow is meant for).

Comment: This question has been posted here:http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67408/problems-connecting-asus-transformer-tf101-to-mac-os-x-10-92 for those aware of this forum. Feel free to comment in either location.

Comment: No, don't comment in either location. Delete this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what worked for me on Mac OS was to run

```
adb kill-server
sudo adb devices
```

and it magically saw my Asus TF701